# Is there a way to make app engine turn off when no traffic

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, mux-video

I am currently using App Engine in Google Cloud with Docker to handle Mux Video requests. The problem is I am being charged over $40 when the app is in development and there is virtually no traffic on the app. Is there a way to turn off the App Engine when no requests are being sent so the hours of operation are less or this not possible with app Engine? I am quite new to App Engine.

```
runtime: custom
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't scale to 0 the Flex instances. It's the main problem of the flex instances.

You have to replace the current service by a APp Engine standard service version that can scale to 0 and stop paying.

---

If your application doesn't run background processes, and the request handling doesn't take more than 60 minutes, I strongly recommend you to have a look to [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run)

Comment: So Cloud Run works like cloud functions in the fact it is on pay per use. However, with cloud run, you can upload dockers to it. Sorry I am new to this

Comment: Right, Cloud Run is a serverless product, like APp ENgine standard, that scale to 0. With Cloud Run you can manage your runtime environment because you can provide your own container. But you can also ask Cloud Run to build a standard container for you (use `gcloud run deploy --source=. ` in your source directory to let Cloud Run build a standard container for you with your code).